# PHP. Удалить из массива определенные ключи

Tags: php, массивы

Каким способом можно удалить из массива элементы ключ которых содержит определенный префикс, к примеру "_ru", либо же "_en"?

Пример:

```
title_en   => '',
title_ru   => '',
section_en => '',
section_ru => ''
```

Каким способом можно удалить из массива все элементы с ключом '_en', либо '_ru'?

Comment: не тем ты путём идёшь....всё было бы намного проще, группируя данные `en => title, section, other...; ru => titile, section, other...`

Comment: Это вывод из БД, в ней подобная структура.

Comment: Плохая структура. В таблице хотя бы можно было колонку для указания языка сделать и уже было бы значительно проще.....Вот представь что у тебя не 2 языка, а 22. Какой кошмар у тебя будет

Comment: Их не 22 конечно, а 3, но тем не менее возникают проблемы. У меня нет возможности изменить структуру базы данных и записей в ней.

Comment: что мешает пройтись по массиву и проверить вхождение суффика в ключ и сделать unset ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Функция удаляет из массива элементы, ключи которых содержат подстроку '_en' или '_ru'

```
function changeArr($array)
{
    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
        if (preg_match('/_en|_ru/', $key)) {
            unset($array[$key]);
        }
    }
    return $array;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно средствами PHP сгруппировать данные. Что имеется ввиду. Берём и разбиваем строку-ключ через функцию `explode`. Далее, если структура у всех ключей будет такой, как описана в вопросе, то мы знаем что результатом `explode('_', $key)` будет массив из 2 элементов. В первом будет лежать, например, `title`, а во-втором будет лежать уже ключ-локаль. Мы можем в новый результирующий массив положить наше текущее значение: `$data[$keyLocale][$keyValue] = $value;` получается примерно следующее: `$data['en']['title'] = '';`.

Примерный исходный код будет выглядеть следующим образом:

```php
function groupData(array $arr, string $separate = '_'): array
{
    $data = [];

    foreach($arr as $key => $value) {
        list($keyValue, $keyLocale) = explode($separate, $key);
        $data[$keyLocale][$keyValue] = $value;
    }

    return $data;
}
```